# No Sound Input Devices Found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I am very new to Linux and have been loving it so far. However, this is the first problem I have run into that I havent been able to trouble shoot online. When I go to my sound setting and try to find an input device nothing appears; however, I have output audio.

[image: screenshot 1]

I ran `arecord -l` and I get the following output:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALCS1200A Analog [ALCS1200A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALCS1200A Alt Analog [ALCS1200A Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I also installed and ran pavucontrol. When I go to input devices nothing appears under show all expect monitors. However, when I switch to all input devices my headphones appear:

[image: screenshot 2]

I when I try to run `pulseaudio -D` it fails. And I get `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.`

I am super lost. Any help would be really appreciated.

My hardware that I am trying to connect to Linux is power beats pro

Comment: Well, some audio hardware is not supported by Linux. State your hardware and add it to your question by using the **Edit** link

Comment: Hey I added the hardware but I am not sure if I did it right. Is there a way I am suppose to add it - i.e. like how do I make sure I put the correct info? Sorry super new!

Answer (score 0):

Looks good sofar. Your hardware is certainly supported, but probably your settings are mixed up.
If pulseaudio is running and you call `pulseaudio -D`: it will fail, since the daemon already runs.

For pavucontrol to configure an output sound two tabs are relevant:

[[image: 1]]

Here you can see where the output goes. Currently my HDMI Port is active, so any sound would come out the monitor speaker.

The configuration page shows you, which cards you have (in my case two cards: the mainboard audio card and the Nvidia HDMI Sound card. Select the "profile", usually similar to what you can see in the picture.

[[image: 2]]

Now I want to decide **where** the sound goes to. Start a program that produces a sound (eg a youtube video)

[[image: 3]]

The "playback" tab is used to direct the output to the correct card.In my example firefox play on my Mainboard card - I do not hear anything, because nothing is connected to the card.
But: I can switch to my monitor with an integrated speaker:

[[image: 4]]

Selecting the HDMI Port works, now I can hear a sound. This behaviour is **not** intuitive, but the maker of this software (L.Poettering) has his very special own ideas and is resistant to most discussions..
Try it out and continue to ask questions...

Comment: Ok so I have been messing around with this for like two weeks now and I still cant figure it out :/. I can get audio coming out but it wont pick up the mic for input. In other words I can hear other people but they cant hear me. Is there other info that might help? When I look at my HDA NVidia and Built-in Audio nearly everything is unplugged/unavaliable expect fore Digital Stero(IEC958) Outpouyt + Analog Stereo Input

Comment: @brzig, did you manage to get this resolved? I'm having a similar issue. I can get sound from my headphones, but no sound from speakers and no audio getting to my mic.

Comment: @TinasheChinyanga I didnt. I bought a mic.